# Looking for ways to draw the given diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

Just a challenging diagram I'm trying to implement when typesetting my course notes.

The context of the diagram is the partial order relation on the power set, the U looking symbol is the subset symbol `$\subset$`.

I thought of trying to create it using `tikz` but I have only had experience drawing basic commutative diagrams..

Also, there's a slightly more difficult diagram showing elements in a chain

Thanks!!

(1)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for in the second diagram. Perhaps post it as a separate question with more specific instructions.

Comment: @SandyG I just also wanted to create the second diagram as it looks but sure I'll post it as another question. I just feel bad for posting diagrams for people to draw when the website is more focused on questions rather than requests.

Comment: For a future question, it would be helpful if you could post the tikz-cd version that you have.  That would give us something to start from.

Comment: @Teepeemm That’s fair, I’ll do that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tikz-cd` for the subset diagram. Use `phantom` arrows labeled with `\subset`. To make the subset symbol follow the arrow use the `sloped` option. Note that for arrows pointing up-left you should use `\supset` since the direction will flip.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb} % to use \varnothing
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
     & \{a,b,c\} \\
    \{a,b\}\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}] & \{a,c\}\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}] & \{b,c\}\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}] \\
    \{a\}\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}, pos=.4] & \{b\}\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}, pos=.4]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}, pos=.4] & \{c\}\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}, pos=.4]\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}] \\
     & \varnothing\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}]\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

To avoid the subset symbols overlapping you can use `pos=.4` or whatever position looks good to you.

As an alternative to the `pos=.4` solution, you could use `xshift`. This has the advantage of keeping the symbols at the same height across the row, but moves them slightly out of line with the two sets:

[image]

The code for these would be

```
\{a\}\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}, xshift=5pt] & 
\{b\}\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}, xshift=-5pt]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}, xshift=5pt] & 
\{c\}\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped},xshift=-5pt]\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}] \\
 & \varnothing\arrow[ul, phantom, "\supset"{sloped}]\arrow[u, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]\arrow[ur, phantom, "\subset"{sloped}]
```

If you want the symbols reversed as they were in the first image, replace the `5pt` shifts with `-3pt` shifts and `-5pt` with `3pt`.

Comment: Yea, I tried using tikzcd but I couldnt get the symbols in the right positions :( What is the phantom option doing for each of the arrows?

Comment: @Hushus46, basically it creates an invisible arrow. The subset symbols are the labels for the phantom arrows.

Comment: Ah I see, you make the arrow invisible and then overlay a label using the subset symbol, cool.